# if elif else blocks evaluate for every case

Tags: python, python-3.5

I am trying to append an iterator to a list but my code below evaluates for every case.

```
Less7=Head7=Over7=[]
i=0

for i in range(0,10):
    if i<7:
        Less7.append(i)

    elif i==7:
        Head7=i

    else:
        Over7.append(i)
```

The result I am getting are:
Head7 is an int value of 7
Less7 and Over7 are lists - [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

My desired results are:

```
Less7=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

Head7=[7]

Over7=[8,9]
```

I'm sure it's basic, could you point me in the right direction?
My thought is that it has to do with the datatype.
When I step through the code, even `Head7` evaluates `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]` but when `i=7` then it correctly assigns the value, but I want it in a list.

Comment: @PadricCunningham when I implemented adding the extra empty lists I get the error AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'. 

Ah Ha! I still had the assignment operator instead of the coma. 
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create *three lists*, one for each possible outcome:

```
less_than_7, is_7, greater_than_7 = [], [], []

for i in range(0, 10):
    if i < 7:
        less_than_7.append(i)
    elif i > 7:
        greater_than_7.append(i)
    else:
        is_7.append(i)
```

*`Less7=Head7=Over7=[]`* creates one list that is referenced by the three names so your output would be identical as you are appending to the same list, well you are in the first and last case, *`Head7=i`* sets *`Head7`* equal to *`i/7`*.

Comment: Thanks! "less_than_7, is_7, greater_than_7 = [], [], []" did not do the trick though, I had to put each statement on a separate line.

Comment: @MechMon, no t sure what you mean, the code works exactly as posted

Comment: You have `Less7=Head7=Over7=[],[],[]` which is very different to `less_than_7, is_7, greater_than_7 = [], [], []"` One creates a single list while  the other creates three.